# Unknown kernel command line parameters "BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.18.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64", will be passed to user space

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, kernel, linux-kernel

On [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7, after upgrading the kernel to version 5.18.11, I observed the below message in */var/log/messages*:

**Unknown kernel command line parameters "BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.18.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64", will be passed to user space.**

What is the root cause for this?